# Apache POI search .txt and replace .docm

Tags: java, regex, replace, apache-poi, docx

I'm using **ApachePOI library** to search&replace in a `.docm` file.
I have a `.txt` with extracted first **3 words** from every page from a PDF file **(same content as `.docm` file).**

I want to get every line from the `.txt` and search inside the `.docm`, when matches , before that particular 3 words I will add a `html` page tag like `<page>(pdfpagenumber)</page>`

EDITED(30.03.2017) My `searchedTemp.txt` looks like:

```
Dieses Buch wendet
Einführung in
b) mit ihm 
Straftäter werden 
etc.
```

EDIT(30.03.2017) The code within APACHE POI looks like this:

```
package dgi.writetags;


import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class App {
    public static  String SOURCE_FILE = "D:" + File.separator + "ReadPageTags" + File.separator + "Doc" + File.separator + "test.docm";
    public static  String OUTPUT_FILE = "D:" + File.separator + "ReadPageTags" + File.separator + "Doc" + File.separator + "output.docm";
    public static  String OUTPUT_SEARCH = "D:" + File.separator + "ReadPageTags" + File.separator + "GeneratedList" + File.separator + "searchTemp.txt";
    public static  String actual;


    //MAIN METHOD
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Application instances
        App docm = new App();
        System.out.println("[DOCM] App started.");

        //Search inside the TXT
        //docm.searchlist();


        //CheckStart
        //System.out.print(docm.searchlist());
        //CheckEnd


        //Replace text in DOCM
        docm.replaceText();


        //Exit after succeed
        //System.exit(0);

    }


    //replace text method
    private void replaceText() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
        App wt = new App();
        String[] lines = wt.searchlist().split("\n");
         XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FILE));
            for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()){
                for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()){

                    String text = r.toString();

                      for(String s : lines){


                        text = text.replace(s, "pagetag "+s);

                        r.setText(text,0);



                }

                }
              System.out.println("[DOCM] Working...");

           }
           doc.write(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
           doc.close();

           System.out.println("[DOCM] Finished");



}



    //search into text file method
    //for the latest method return STRING
    private String searchlist() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(OUTPUT_SEARCH));
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            buf.append(line);
            buf.append(System.lineSeparator());
            if (line == null) break;

        }
        br.close();

        return buf.toString();


    }
```

Even if I remove the `while loop`,or add some `regex`, or do it in other ways the same, it won't replace...

P.S.: Oh, and if I get only the third line it throws me an error with the ")" part.

Comment: Your code is initializing and writing a `XWPFDocument thedoc`. But the changings are made in an object `doc` which is not initialized in your code.

Comment: I resolved that issue and modified this last night but still don't works...
My output now is the .txt lines and inside the .docm it just don't search&replace...

Eclipse console output:
"[DOCM] App started.(newline)
Abtretung 124 Bedeutung (newline)

Vorwort Dieses Buch (newline)

Einführung in (newline)"

and the 
docm is unchanged..

Comment: I believe the `text` you are getting from the runs is not what you are supposing because of the strange kind how `Word` will split text into runs sometimes. Check it using `System.out.println(text);` after the `String text = r.toString();`. In my opinion it will be nearly impossible to achieve what you want. We can replacing properly defined placeholders with text or putting text into fields. But replacing random text, which can randomly be splitted in different runs, is a very complex task.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @AxelRichter , I always check in `System.out.println();` before running and they work well sir. I will try with a different approach. Well, I think the word **"impossible"** in this task gives me the hope.